# [php] регулярки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Вот в принципе известно одно постоянное id="mess_str", остальной код меняется время от времени, мне нужно вытащить что в теге <a></a> т.е. 118 писем

подскажите регулярку.

```
<a id="mess_str" href="/mess?act=msg" onclick="if (checkEvent(event) === false) { ajax.post('all_mess.php', {act: 'get_msg'}, {}); return false; }">118 писем</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё очень просто! =)

```
id="mess_str"[^>]*>(.*?)<
```

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/imEDNC)

Comment: ваще четко!!!